# Using IHttpClientFactory in Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, ihttpclientfactory

I would like to use `IHttpClientFactory` in a WPF application built using the Prism library. I have added two packages, Prism.Unity and Prism.Unity.Extensions and i attempt to register the `IHttpClientFactory` with the following code:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterServices(s => s.AddHttpClient("DefaultClient")
                                         .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy()));
```

However, I get the following error:

[image: Type load exception for CreateScope in Prism.Unity.ContainerExtension.]

I have also added the following override:

```
protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension() => PrismContainerExtension.Current;
```

Comment: Are your references correct? This looks like a wrong dll or two.

Comment: I cannot get the version 8 on NuGet, for the extension packages. My Prism is version 8. Are you able to achieve this task on your end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prism 8 introduces registration methods for *scoped services*. The `IContainerProvider` interface declares an additional method [`CreateScope`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Prism.Core/Ioc/IContainerProvider.cs#L45) and a member [`CurrentScope`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/1046aee5cca5b40e073f1dbc06c09ed7a5506dc7/src/Prism.Core/Ioc/IContainerProvider.cs#L50) that were not present in earlier versions.

```
public interface IContainerProvider {
   // ...other members.

   IScopedProvider CreateScope();

   ScopedProvider CurrentScope { get; }
}
```

The `PrismContainerExtension` classes from *Prism.Unity.Extensions* in version *7.2.0.1054* and earlier do **not** implement this method. Consequently, you get an exception using it with Prism 8.

Since the types are incompatible, you either have to revert to *Prism 7.2.0.1054* or you have to wait for a new version of *Prism.Unity.Extensions* that supports the new scoped services in Prism 8. There are already changes made in the repository, but a preview version is currently [only available to sponsors](https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Container.Extensions#nuget).